# Returning x amount of API movie into unordered list using React, Axios, and MovieDB

Tags: reactjs, api

I am making a movie search app using React, Axios, and MovieDB API. Currently, it returns all the information I want it to by searching for a movie. However, I ran into an issue where movies that share a title with more popular movies don't show up and there is no way of accessing them. I am trying to add a side section that's titled "show similar" where I can have all the other titles that share the name show up in the unordered list. I do not know how to implement a for or for each function in React js that would be able to get each title outside of the first title `['0']` that it is returning.

You can access a different movie with the same name by changing the number `['0']`, `['1']`, etc.
Here is a picture for reference
[image]

The code is in Movielist and the other two are listed in case you need.

Movielist.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../CSS/style.css'

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    popularity: "",
    poster: "",
    background: "",
    results: "",
  }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = 'caf02a958f137f43327649b2b8721302';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {

        this.setState({ results: res.data.results })

        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

        const popularity = res.data['results'][0]['popularity']
        this.setState({ popularity });

        const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']
        this.setState({ poster });

        const background = res.data['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
        this.setState({ background })


      })
        }
    }

  render() {
    const backgroundStyle = {
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), 
  url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`,

      backgroundSize: "cover",
      height: "100vh"
  }


    return (
      <div id="main-div" style={backgroundStyle}>
      <div id="second-div">
       <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
       <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
       <h1 id="title">Title: {this.state.title}</h1>
       <h1 id="popularity">Popularity: {this.state.popularity}</h1>
       <img id="poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${this.state.poster}`} />
    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'



function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Movielist />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Do you want the similar movies for a movie that was searched or show the list of movies that share the same search query and were returned as results? For example do you want to get all the similar movies for 'joker' or do you want to get all the other movies that was returned from the API when you searched for 'joker'?

Comment: All the ones that share the same title.

Comment: Try `res.data.results.slice(1)` and tell me if that was the result you were looking for or not?

Comment: I tried putting that in brackets and it says ```res is not defined``` and I tried making that into a const and returning the const and it said the const was not defined. Then I tried adding that to state and using setState and it was saying data was not defined

Comment: Don't try to setState or anything, just try to `console.log` the value of `res.data.results.slice(1)` after you make the API call in axios.get('yourapiendpoint').then((res) => { console.log(res.data.results.slice(1) }). And see if that gives you the list of movies that you want.

Comment: yes the console.log is the list I want

Comment: Nice, I will be posting the complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new state variable to store the movies that share a similar title.
And set the state value for the `similarMovies` as the array of results you get from the API call excluding the first index. For example,

```js
state = {
    title: "",
    popularity: "",
    poster: "",
    background: "",
    results: "",
    similarMovies: [] // create an empty array for similarMovies
  }

// in the click handler update the state
clickHandler = (event) => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     const query = event.target.value;
     const API_KEY = 'caf02a958f137f43327649b2b8721302';
     axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {

        this.setState({ results: res.data.results });
        // here we set the state value
        const similarMovies = res.data.results.slice(1);
        this.setState({ similarMovies })

        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

        const popularity = res.data['results'][0]['popularity']
        this.setState({ popularity });

        const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']
        this.setState({ poster });

        const background = res.data['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
        this.setState({ background })


      })
        }
    }
```

Then you can render the movies in an unordered list by mapping over the value of `this.state.similarMovies`.

```js
return (
      <div id="main-div" style={backgroundStyle}>
      <div id="second-div">
       <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
       <ul>
         {
           this.state.similarMovies.length && this.state.similarMovies.map(movie => (
              <li>
                <h3>{movie.title}</h3>
                /*Other details you want to show*/
              <li>

          ))
         }
       </ul>
       <h1 id="title">Title: {this.state.title}</h1>
       <h1 id="popularity">Popularity: {this.state.popularity}</h1>
       <img id="poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${this.state.poster}`} />
    </div>
  </div>
    )
```